# Bootstrap Condensed Nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, stacked

Does anybody know if there's a nav-condensed option (or workaround) in Bootstrap?  I know there's a table-condensed class, but would like to cram more data into a stacked nav bar.  Something like the code below would be great.  Thanks!

```
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked nav-condensed">
                        <li>
                            <a id="popupName"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="popupAge"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="popupActivity"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new selector in your CSS to overrule the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` rules of the `.nav-tabs > li > a` selector. See bootstrap.css line 4068 (as per the CSS file used on the Bootstrap documentation site).

```
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-condensed > li > a {
   padding-top: 4px; 
   padding-bottom: 4px; 
}
/*original padding value 8px*/
```